# Migrated question from Stackoverflow with no updating of reputation

Tags: support, reputation, close-reasons, migration, stackoverflow

I got a question migrated from Stackoverflow [Visual Programming paradigms](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119463/visual-programming-paradigms), and it continues to be responding, so my reputation on Programmers should increase. However I did not get any increase from any actions since the 5 points from the question creation.

Is this behavior right? I mean, we get no points from migrated questions here?

PS.: If this is not the right place for me to ask this kind of question, please inform me on how to proceed before closing this, ok? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in the right place to ask this question.

You don't receive reputation when someone responds to your question. Your question received one upvote, which added 5 reputation to your account for a total of 6, so everything seems to be working as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I really didn't remember this from faq.